# Hash Code for a group of three fields

Tags: java, hashcode

I have three fields, namely

1. Number1
2. Number2
3. Time

I am trying to write a function in java that returns a unique hash value (**long needs to be the return type of hash**) for the above fields. This hash would then be used to store database rows corresponding to the above mentioned fields in a HashSet. I am new to writing a hash code function, can someone please review what I have.

```
public class HashCode {

    private long Number1;
    private long Number2;
    String Time;

    public HashCode(long Number1, long Number2, String Time){
        this.Number1 = Number1;
        this.Number2 = Number2;
        this.Time = Time;
    }

    public long getHashCode() {
        long hash = 3;
        hash = 47 * hash + (long) (this.Number1 ^ (this.Number1 >>> 32));
        hash = 47 * hash + (long) (this.Number2 ^ (this.Number2 >>> 32));
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.Time != null ? this.Time.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it's a special version of hashCode. Otherwise you would need to overwrite `hashCode`, don't define a new method. Containers like `HashSet` don't get your own hash code.

- So for your specialized version for `long`, you do not need to use the xor (^) because it's already long. Just use the `long` value.
- When using hashCode of String it's not for long, just for int, so it will not "use" all your space. You could duplicate the `hashCode` of String with `long`s for your purpose.
- else looks good.

(By the way, members should be called with lower letters and `Time` should be private as well.)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and not have to worry about doing this by hand anymore.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
 // you pick a hard-coded, randomly chosen, non-zero, odd number
 // ideally different for each class
 return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).
   append(Number1).
   append(Number2).
   append(Time).
   toHashCode();
}
```

btw, it's convention in Java for variable names to start with a lowercase. You're going to find it confusing to name variables things like `Number1`, `Number2`, etc., as people will confuse these with the names of types (such as `String`, `Number`, `Long`, etc.).