# Java hash of 2 hashes

Tags: java, hashcode

I'm having two lists of objects, users and products

users own products, and each products is associated to 1 user

but a product type can be multiple and be owned by separate users

- users: Ed, Rob
- products: Coca, Sprites(1), Sprites(2), Beer
- Ed has Coca and Sprites(1), Rob Sprites (2) and Beer

I need to generate an id for each unique (user+product)

It's probably not a good idea to do

```
user.hashCode() + product.hashCode()
```

What could be a good way to proceed?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587442/hash-code-for-a-group-of-three-fields

Comment: `(37*(17 + user.hashCode) + product.hashCode())`. Taken from Effective Java.

Comment: Hashcodes are not unique. Equal objects return the same hashcode, but the same hashcode does not mean that objects are equal. Don't mistake hashcode for an ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `hashCode` is not that bad if both user and product create pseudo-random hash-codes. If you are afraid of hash collisions because of bad hashCode implementations in either `user` or `product`, then multiply one of the source hash codes by a prime number:

```
public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((product == null) ? 0 : product.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((user == null) ? 0 : user.hashCode());
  return result;
}
```

Eclipse builds this very code when selecting *Source | Generate hashCode() and equals()*.

As mentioned by Thilo, you can also simply use `Arrays.hashCode(new Object[]{ user, product })`; This call takes care of `null` values for user or product and also multiplies the result by 31 - same as the hand written code.
If you are using Google Guava, there is an `Objects.hashCode(Object...)` that makes your intent a little bit clearer and uses varargs, but it also only delegates to `Arrays.hashCode`.

Comment: so here you are using the same prime number as multiplier of user and product, why don't take 2 different ones?

Comment: @ca11111 there is already a post at stackoverflow that answers this much better than I ever could: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1147232/112964

Answer (score 5):

You could let Apache Commons [HashCodeBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) do the work for you.

It lets you write something like

```
return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).
   append(user).
   append(product).
   toHashCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to multiply the first hash with a prime number and then add the second hash.

Answer (score 0):

We need to do two points:

1. minimize collisions
2. hash(a,b)!=hash(b,a)

I suggest such way:

[image]

numerically we have such algorithm:

```
a = hash1
b = hash2
p = a+b
result_hash = p*(p+1)/2+b
```

but if we reduce algorithm, this will not affect collisions:

```
a = hash1
b = hash2
p = a+b
result_hash = p*p+b
```

we can check this (in python):

```
N=256 # number of different values of hash
d = {}
for a in range(N):
  for b in range(N):
    p = a+b
    x = (p*p+b)%N
    if x in d:
      d[x]+=1
    else:
      d[x]=1
print(max(v for k,v in d.items()))
```