# how to remove alike array in a 2d array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

a 2d array like below:

```
[[-1 2 -1] [-1 1 0] [-1 0 1] [-1 -1 2] [-1 2 -1]]
```

i want to keep one of `[-1 1 0] [-1 0 1]` and one of `[-1 2 -1] [-1 -1 2] [-1 2 -1]`.

because the arrays in each group are alike to others with the same value but different sequece, so i just want to keep one of each group.

result i want is some like below:

```
[[-1 2 -1] [-1 1 0]]
```

or

```
[[-1 -1 2],[-1 0 1]]
```

is there any ideas to realize that.

Comment: probably implement a [hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587442/hash-code-for-a-group-of-three-fields) for the group of three elements in the array and insert each array into a set.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: All you're doing iis de-dup-ing the top-level array.  There are plenty of resources for how to remove duplicates from a sequence.

Comment: @Prune thank you for pointing out my issues. As you can see my poor english is the problem to search out answers efficiently from google, and when i post this question i had seen some same problems but with no answers. Anyway i would keep searching for answers.  thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

As [@SomeDude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714147/how-to-remove-alike-array-in-a-2d-array#comment96214449_54714147) suggested, you can create some sort of hashing function that generates a unique code for each set of values, regardless of the order they come in. Then add each value of hash map using that hash function. The output would just be the values of the hash map.

Here's a very simple implementation in JavaScript:

```js
const input = [[-1, 2, -1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2], [-1, 2, -1]];
const toHash = (arr) => [...arr].sort().join();
const hashSet = input.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[toHash(cur)] = cur, acc), {});
const output = Object.values(hashSet);
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

The performance (and accuracy) of this algorithm would depend primarily on your choice of hash function.

Comment: thank you for answering.  Actually i was doing some leetcode practices, so i was wondering if there's a way use no hash or lib??
i have a idea, but i think that is too slow:
i have to sort(which is a time consuming part, i do not want to use until no other ways left) each array, then make a number string(which needs to convert int to string) or some type could be a key of a map/set, last i could judge if it exists in a map/set.

is there a better one??  thank you for teaching me!

Comment: @touchstone If all of your inner arrays are pretty small (in your example, they're all length 3), sorting is trivial. But more generally, it depends on what kind of assumptions you can make about your data. If all of the arrays only store a limited number of distinct values (in your example, `-1`, `0`, `1`, and `2`) then you could simply use a 32-bit int to store flags. Even if you have to search through all arrays to count the number of distinct values before you start hashing, that's technically a O(n) operation as opposed to sorting which is O(n log n).